# Regex in JS: .search() space and parenthesis

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, search, match

I want to .search() for `$( #nav ul li)`. The spaces should be regarded.

So far i got: `(\s)*$(\s)*\((\s)*#nav(\s)+ul(\s)+li(\s)*\)(\s)*`

`(\s)*$` this part seems to works, and so does `(\s)*\(`

but if i put it together, it wont work.
What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` is a special character in regex which matches the end of the line boundary. You must need to escape that in-order to match a literal `$` symbol.

```
(\s)*\$(\s)*\((\s)*#nav(\s)+ul(\s)+li(\s)*\)(\s)*
```

And remove the unnecessary groups.

```
\s*\$\s*\(\s*#nav\s+ul\s+li\s*\)\s*
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bN8dG9/1)